# Not able to resolve :Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried looking for the answer in the similar questions but I am not able to resolve, I know the error is due to the jquery ,DOM conversion but I am not able to fix the issue, I have tried to use append(); instead of appendChild();. I am trying to implement drag and drop functionality.

This is my javascript:(The commented is the methods I have tried )

```
$('#todo, #inprog').bind('drop', function(event) {
    var notecard = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(notecard));
    // var c = $(document.getElementById(notecard))[0];
    // var c = $('#notecard')[0];
    //event.target.innerHTML = document.getElementById(notecard);
    //event.target.append(notecard);
    //$(event.target).append(document.getElementById(notecard));
    //$(event.target).append('#notecard');
    //$('#notecard').appendTo(event.target);
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: The error will be because `document.getElementById(notecard)` is returning null, because there is no element with the id of the value of the `notecard` variable. What is the value of `notecard`? Check for any trailing spaces/ new lines in the file you're dropping.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `notecard` is not a `node`.

Do some changes in your code

```
$('#todo, #inprog').bind('drop', function(event) {
  var notecardText = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  var notecard = document.createElement("div"); // Create a node first, div or p or span
  notecard.appendChild(notecardText) // append your text to the node
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(notecard));
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Still not getting it resolved now there is no error but it doesnt work

Comment: So this problem resolved. Check the return value of `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");` null or not. Or provide a jsFiddle

Comment: I am still getting the exception

Comment: @DhruvGoyal Can you please show the returned value of event.originalEvent‌​.dataTransfer.getData‌​("text/plain");

Comment: I dont know why it is returning null

Comment: No its supposed to return value from here `$('#itemT1, #item2').bind('dragstart', function(event) {
                event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the DOM object was not loaded for the elements created dynamically and I was calling the js function before they are created so `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plai‌​n");` was returning null as there was no element was present when the js loaded. I called the function where the DOM was created to solve the issue.
Like this `'<div id="itemT'+j+'" name="task'+j+'" draggable="true" contenteditable class="cardTitle" ondragstart="dragS1(event)"></div>'`